# Order execution of create table using mysql, h2 and flyway

Tags: java, mysql, junit, h2, flyway

I have created a an sql script (using mysqldump) to determine my base version of my database. I use this script with flywaydb to totally manage the db creation and other migration actions. The script contains of several tables some of them are fk's to others. the order in which they appear in the sql script generated by mysqldump is the following (only two of the tables appear that are causing the issue described later below)

```
CREATE TABLE `signaling_interface` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `test_server_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_sigInterfaceConstraint` (`test_server_id`),
  KEY `FK_3crdx5y8had0g1mit1k2gebt5` (`test_server_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_3crdx5y8had0g1mit1k2gebt5` FOREIGN KEY (`test_server_id`) REFERENCES `test_server` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `test_server` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_3754w88bn333h1dgambvwj6i8` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I want to Junit test my migrations and chose h2 in memory database to do that. But when I try to migrate it gives me an error when creating signaling_interface table because test_server does not exist. It doesn't give me this error when executing migrations in MySQL. Is there a difference between mysql and h2?

Comment: why don't you run the script 2 times, first time dependent tables will not be created and second time it will be created.

Comment: it gets executed by flyway so it throws an exception, and does not create any tables.

Comment: Refer http://matthewcasperson.blogspot.in/2013/07/exporting-from-mysql-to-h2.html link, it appears that you need to manually format the dump.